# How many 4 digit numbers greater than or equal 3000 and less than 8000 can be formed with no repetition in their digits?

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many 4 digit numbers greater than or equal to 3000 and less than 8000 can be formed with no repetition in their digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's: 5 * 9 * 8 * 7

1. You can choose 5 numbers on the first place (3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
2. You can choose 10 - 1 (choosen in 1.) numbers -> 9
3. 9 - 2 (choosen in 1 and 2) -> 8
4. 9 - 3 (3 numbers on previous positions) -> 7

Comment: Oh okay that deffinately helped me thanks,  I believe actually it would be slot one is 5 two is 9 (digits 0 through 9 excluding the first digit)  then slot three is 8 and slot seven would be 7? Leaving me with an answer of 2520?

Comment: @DougMccoppen you're right. I've edited.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

For all numbers between $3000$ and $3999$, you first choose the first leading "3" then it remains three "slots" which cannot be filled by a "3", this leaves you $\frac{9!}{6!}$ possibilities. (Since you have 9 numbers to choose without repetition and the order matters)

Same argument for $[4000,4999], ... , [7000,7999]$

Comment: Isn't it `9!/6!` possibilities?

Comment: My bad, I always forget there are 10 digits :p